# Images from public folder not displayed on github pages when deployed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment, github-pages

I have a react app with certain images being stored in assets in src folder of React app. I'm trying to import all images from that respective folder but throws error. Consider following folder structure.

```
src-->
   assets-->
         all-images-->
                   23450.jpg
                   33670.jpg
                   88976.jpg
                   22345.jpg
                   12554.jpg
```

Now the import is done in following

```
import AllImg from '../assets/all-images'

const GeneralCard = ({allData}) => {

       allData && allData?.map((data) => {
         const {id, name} = data;
        <img src={`${AllImg}/${id}.jpg`} />
})
}
```

```
const allData = [
{id: "23450", name:"John"},
{id: "33760", name:"Alex"},
{id: "88976", name:"Mike"},
{id: "22345", name:"Roy"},
{id: "12554", name:"Rock"},
]

const NewCard = () => {

return (
<GeneralCard allData={allData} />
)
}
```

So as you can see from above, how the mapping of data is done, but, It throws error `Can't resolve "../assets/all-images"`

On the contrary, when I store the images in `public folder` it works fine in localhost, but images are not shown when deployed on github pages

What could be the optimum solution?